# Maven project + Clearcase interproject deliveries issues

Tags: maven, clearcase

We are using Clearcase and we migrate our big project to Maven. We are facing a problem when doing inter project deliveries.

We have a development CC project where most development occurs. We have `pom.xml` that holds versions of our dependencies to our own sub-projects (these versions are maven/pom version).

At some point, we deliver code in production. So we create another CC project. So now we have our main CC project (`MAIN`) and a new one base on it that holds production code (`PROD`).

The `PROD` CC project has a fix version (in the `pom.xml`). For example 1.1.0. The MAIN branch continue to evolve (version 1.2.0, 1.3.0, ...). So the "same" `pom.xml` in both files are different.

The problem occurs when we want to provide a patch (or a feature) in production: we modify the `PROD` CC project and we ship it in production (with an updated version: 1.1.1). Then we want to do an inter project delivery from `PROD` to `MAIN`, to avoid writing the code twice. When we do so, the `pom.xml` file from `DEV` got overridden with those from PROD with older version dependencies and artifact versions.

We tried to use profiles and environment variable to solve this, but with no success. If anyone when through this issues and found a clever solution ?

Thanks for your help,

-Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the automatic merge done during the UCM inter-project deliver.
One solution would be to:

- checkout/checking the pom.xml file in the *destination* stream first,
- then perform the deliver which would trigger a non-trivial merge on that file, allowing you to restore the destination file (i.e. not taking the source version, with the PROD label references)

Comment: I have to suppose this is correct (and maybe my opinion is biased but I'm happy I never had to work with CC). +1

Comment: @Pascal: thank you, and yes, bias or not, you are lucky to not know this particular beast ;)

Comment: I agree with both of you :-) I'm still hoping for someone to propose an unexpected magical solution... Like a way to exclude particulat files (poms) form interproject deliveries but not in-project deliveries without tons of triggers and Perl script...